# Constructible subset of constructible set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $F \subset E \subset X$ be subsets. Assume that $E$ is constructible in $X$ and that $F$ is constructible in $E$. Is it true that $F$ is constructible in $X$?

We use the definition of constructible as defined in EGA I (first edition).

This is true if $X$ has a basis for the topology consisting of quasi-compact opens, see [Lemma Tag 09YJ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09YJ). In particular, it holds if $X$ is a scheme. Thus our question is a bit frivolous as the important use case is covered.

Still: Is there a counter example for general $X$? Is it true if $X$ is quasi-compact?

Answer (score 3):

If $F$ is open in $E$ (where $E$ carries the subspace topology from $X$), then $F = E \cap U$ where $U$ is open in $X$, hence $F$ is constructible in $X$ (since constructibles are closed under intersection). Similarly, if $F$ is closed in $E$, then $F$ is constructible in $X$.

The constructibles in $E$ constitute the smallest Boolean algebra that contains the open and closed sets in $E$. The constructibles in $X$ are a Boolean algebra which, we have just seen, include the open and closed sets in $E$. Hence constructibles in $E$ are included in the the constructibles of $X$, as anticipated.

Comment: An open is not constructible in general, because in EGA I the definition of a constructible starts with retrocompact opens. So your argument works for Noetherian spaces but not in general.

Comment: Okay, but let me note that I was following Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_%28topology%29. If there is something online you could link to for the definition you intend, or if you could recall the definition, then that might help. (What's does retrocompact mean?)

Comment: @ToddTrimble Retrocompact is defined here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0059

Comment: @ToddTrimble: An open subset of an affine scheme is retrocompact iff it is quasicompact, ie. if the complementary closed subset is defined (as a set) by finitely many equations. An open subset of a scheme is retrocompact if and only if its trace on any open affine subscheme is retrocompact (it suffices to consider open affine subschemes forming an open covering).

Comment: @ToddTrimble It seems the wikipedia page is wrong and the statement of Chevalley's theorem there is only correct for morphisms of Noetherian schemes.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, guys.